# How old is Conan meant to be?

Tags: detective-conan

I was rewatching an old episode of Detective Conan with a friend and we started discussing how weird it would be to hear a young child say some of the things Conan says. Then, I realized I didn't know the exact age that Conan was really supposed to be acting. I don't recall Conan's age to ever be mentioned in the show. How old is Conan supposed to be now? What was his age before he shrank?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course, Conan's real age is the same as his age before he shrank. He was 16 at the time he shrank.

Conan does mention his age in the first volume of the manga in File 2, when he almost accidentally tells Ran that he is 16, instead of 6.

[image]

Later in the series, Conan's age is 7, as he has experienced a birthday.

[image]

Conan is also around the same size as other kids that age, which is probably why he was put in class 1-B when he started going to grade school. In Japan, first-year grade school students are between the ages of 6 and 7.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

He is 6 in the manga 7 later (probably had a birthday).

In the subbed anime, he was 17 before he turned into a kid and he is currently 7 years old.

In the Funimation dub, he is 8. During episode seventeen, Conan thinks to himself “Man, being an 8-year-old is embarrassing”.

Answer (score 1):

In Chapter 2, one of the policemen who found him just after he passed away from the Organization's experimental poison estimates that he is 5 or 7 years old.

Later in the same chapter, he tells Ran he is 6 (as mentioned by @giraffesyo)

Answer (score 1):

In 1996 he was 16 and was made to take a drug that makes you ten years younger, so his appearance is that of a 6 year old.

Fast forward over twenty Christmas and New Years specials and he's still the same age.

[image]